# how to compare two string that read from csv file and saved in string array

Tags: java, string, csv, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I read some records from a csv file and store them into a string type array, then save each field in proper variable after convert them. In a part of code I have to compare a field in array with one of those variables with string type. both these arrays filled from a csv file.

```
            int count=0;
            String name=resourceArray[i][j+1] ;
            while(machineArray[count][0]==name)
            {

                machineID=Integer.parseInt(machineArray[count][1]);
                machinePe=Integer.parseInt(machineArray[count][2]);
                count++;
             }
```

the problem is 'while' condition never become true. I debug it and I'm sure machineArray[0][0] and 'name' have same value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strings do not always have the same identity (although it is common).  Try:

```
machineArray[count][0].equals(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your condition from `machineArray[count][0]==name` to `machineArray[count][0].equals(name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are comparing pointers to two String objects by using == instead of comparing Strings.

To compare Strings you have to use Strings equals method:

```
machineArray[count][0].equals(name)
```